# How to check size of a file in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to check the size of my file using echo $_FILES['photo']['size'] but nothing is being returned.

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="sendToDatabase.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Artwork</legend>
        <label>Album Artwork</label>
        <input type="file" name="art" />
        <p>
            File must be saved as a .jpg file.<br />Please crop to 150px wide X 200px tall before uploading.
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Album" class="submitBtn" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_FILES['art']['size']; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into form tag

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"


<form method="POST" action="sendToDatabase.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Comment: you need this for the upload to work, not just chek the file sizw

Comment: @iCoders rtfm is agreeing with you. They're saying `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is required to make the file upload in the first place, not just to be able to check the file size.

Comment: @EdCottrell.ya got it .i confused a bit while reading comment.sorry for that

Comment: @rtfm.sorry i mis understood your comment.you are right